# Why is my loop function to create 4 divs wrong?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Im practicing using loops and what I did was:

```
var writing = function() {

for (var i = 0, n = 4; i < n; i++) {
    document.createElement("div") += 1;
}

};
writing();
```

It didnt work, why is that? It should create 4 divs.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didnt work"? Please be more specific

Comment: Creating element doesn't mean it will be shown on the page.

Comment: @chiwangc the idea is simple. Create a div 4 times and display it on a page. It doesnt display anything

Comment: @u_mulder what am I missing out then?

Comment: Start off by looking at the console, to see what kinds of errors are reported. In case you don't know what the console is, please learn about that right away before you do anything else. You'll also need to learn about DOM calls such as `appendChild`. What is your intention in adding 1 to the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is kind of same. Talking about your code,

this line..

```
document.createElement("div") += 1;
```

is an invalid assignment and will not increment the DOM element count. Keep the things simple. Following is my edit..

```
var writing = function() {
var elm;
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        elm = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(elm);
    }

};
```

Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kidaxuloho/1/edit?html,output)..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vv0z7ux5/21/   I made a jsfiddle version without the click

Comment: How did you learn to code so good? I am learning from the eloquent javascript book and finished chapter two control flow etc. Since the examples were all with console.log I wanted to see how to implement it in the DOM.  Is the entire for loop a variable called elm? why is there no = sign after elm, I see you added semicolon

Comment: I intentially call your function on click handler just to control the execution and working..:)

Comment: what is this kind of variable type you are using with elm? usually variables have = after them

Comment: Doing coding is you are telling a story and its all bout your imagination. JavaScript is not a strongly type language and it doesn't stop you if a variable left undefined.

Comment: Generally it is a good practice not to create a variable inside for loop otherwise it will be created in each iteration. Just stick to the basics and keep reading the good blogs. There is plenty of information available from experts.. :)

Comment: Ah, is it a shortcut for doing var elm = ""; ?   http://jsfiddle.net/vv0z7ux5/26/

Comment: by the way is it normal to fail exercises and not being able to succeed in coding eventhough you understand the concepts? I just started javascript

Comment: It is natural, but make sure you learn with every failure. These are not blockers, but opportunities.

Comment: thank you for your high quality answer upvoted and accepted. Is there any way to add friends or something in stackoverflow?

Comment: you can take a [tour of stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), besides you can not make friends as it is not a social networking site. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="div1">The text above has been created dynamically.</div>
</body>
```

JS :

```
var writing = function() {

  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 

   for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); 
   newDiv.appendChild(newContent);

   document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
}

};
writing();
```

I hope this will help you

Click to see [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vv0z7ux5/2/)

Comment: this part confused me var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");

Comment: why do we need this if there is no div1? I mean what if there is no div

Comment: Why would you re-retrieve `currentDiv` each time through the loop?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vv0z7ux5/13/  I think it is abit more cleaner but I dont want to append any text. Removing the variable that container the text destroy the function